# ¿Cómo construir un array para pasarlo a json en php?

Tags: php, javascript

Necesito construir un `array` y después pasarlo a `json` pero que me quede de la siguiente forma,(imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente :

```
$formaspago[] = array('Tarjeta','Gift Card','Descuento');
       $cantidades[] = array($stmt_tarjeta['can_tarjeta'],$stmt_gitCard['can_gift'],$stmt_Descuentos['can_descuentos']);

  for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){

          $data[] = array($formaspago[$i],$cantidades[$i]);

      }
```

Esta parte es js:

```
  var jugos = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;

    console.log(jugos);
```

No se que parte estoy haciendo mal, cuando le doy console log me sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se forman dos array  y yo necesito que se formen en pares , ahora se forma así mi array:

```
array(2)
{ 
    [0]=> array(2)
    { 
        [0]=> array(3)
        { 
            [0]=> string(7) "Tarjeta" 
            [1]=> string(9) "Gift Card" 
            [2]=> string(9) "Descuento" 
        } 
        [1]=> array(3)
        { 
            [0]=> string(1) "8" 
            [1]=> string(1) "1" 
            [2]=> string(1) "1" 
        } 
    } 
    [1]=> array(2)
    { 
        [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL 
    } 
}
```

Yo necesito que se formen de la siguiente forma:

```
array(4)
{ 
    [0]=> array(2)
    { 
        [0]=> string(9) "Nivélate" 
        [1]=> string(1) "6" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(2)
    { 
        [0]=> string(11) "Enciéndete" 
        [1]=> string(1) "1" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(2) 
    { 
        [0]=> string(9) "Actívate" 
        [1]=> string(1) "1" 
    } 
    [3]=> array(2) 
    { 
        [0]=> NULL
    }
}
```

Comment: esta bien el codigo no veo ningin error, es normal que el console.log te salga de esa forma, lo que debes verificar es como estas generando el array

Comment: si eso verifique y me genera dos array y  yo necesito como en la imagen en pares varios array

Comment: puedes colocar el array de salida?, y cual es el json esperado

Comment: @JackNavaRow eso le dará arrays asociativos. El OP quiere un array de 3 parejas. Yo hice una prueba usando http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5532ef6a79ab268803e225567b202e7f04c9718c y funciona acorde a lo esperado. Ahora, ojo, en vez de `$formaspago[] = array('Tarjeta','Gift Card','Descuento');` yo estoy usando `$formaspago = array('Tarjeta','Gift Card','Descuento');`. El contexto de la pregunta cambia si acaso `$formaspago` es un array plano o es un array de arrays

Comment: gracias amigo !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Cuando estas creando los `array` `$formaspago` y `$cantidades` lo estás haciendo mal por que estás diciendo que al `array` en el índice `0` le agregue otro `array` y debería de ser que la variable como tal tiene como valor un `array`. En resumen debes cambiar esto `$formaspago[] = [...]` por esto `$formaspago = [...]`
2. Para que el ciclo `for` pueda recorrer todas las posiciones debes hacerlo así `for($i=0; $i<=2; $i++)` o así `for($i=0; $i < 3; $i++)`
3. La forma correcta de adicionar valores a un `array` es por medio del método `array_push()`

Te dejo el código completo:

```
$data = [];

$formaspago = ['Tarjeta','Gift Card','Descuento'];
$cantidades = [5, 10, 15];

for($i=0; $i<=2; $i++){
    array_push($data, array($formaspago[$i], $cantidades[$i]));
}

echo '<script>console.log('. json_encode($data) .')</script>';
```

Comment: Básicamente, hay que hacer hincapié en que debe declarar los arrays usando `$formaspago = [...]` y no `$formaspago[] = [...]`. Y claro, está el tema de recorrer 3 elementos y no 2.  Creo que usar `array_push` o `$data[]` es equivalente.

Comment: @amenadiel agregaré el ejemplo a la respuesta para que se entienda mejor, gracias, en cuanto a array_push() siempre prefiero usar los métodos que provee PHP, hay versiones anteriores en las que [] no se reconocen como array y saca error si el OP está trabajando en esas versiones le va a sacar un dolor de cabeza solucionar ese error. Saludos.

Comment: Igual que @amandiel te recomiendo usar `[]` (PHP compatible >=5.4), consume menos recursos. También ser consistente en el código, ej: `data = []` no funcionaria con versiones inferiores al 5.4